# How to load versioned resources in a karma unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner

Please, find below my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    var path = require("path"),
        basePath = "../../../../../..",
        version = require(path.join(__dirname, basePath, "ThirdPartyJsLibRootMap.json"));

    config.set({
        basePath: basePath,
        frameworks: ['intern'],
        files: [
            'Tools/Karma/dojo-config.js',
            'http://devstatic/libraries/dojo-debug/' + version['dojo-debug'] + '/dojo/dojo.js',
            ...
        ],
        reporters: ['progress', 'html'],
        htmlReporter: {
            outputFile: 'Tools/Karma/HRunitTestReport.html'
        },
        port: 9876,
        colors: false,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

The `files` section specifies a few files, but the most important ones are:

- `Tools/Karma/dojo-config.js`
- `http://devstatic/libraries/dojo-debug/' + version['dojo-debug'] + '/dojo/dojo.js`

Notice, that all the 3rd party dependencies are served from a dedicated server - **devstatic**. It is sort of an internal CDN. The 3rd party content is also versioned and the versions used by the current revision of our application are stored in a dedicated json file - **ThirdPartyJsLibRootMap.json**, which is part of the application.

The aforementioned karma.conf.js works, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I have a feeling that the **files** section is not intended to hold http urls. And I am pretty sure it will not work with expressions like `**`.

But there is more. `Tools/Karma/dojo-config.js` is responsible for common configuration and it looks like this:

```
window.__karma__.loaded = function () { };
setImmediate = function (fn) { fn(); };

dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: "http://devstatic/libraries/dojo-debug/1.10.4",
    async: true,
    useDeferredInstrumentation: true,
    has: {
        'host-karma': true
    },
    paths: {
        'Globalization': 'http://devstatic/libraries/globalization-debug/0.1.1',
        'put-selector': 'http://devstatic/libraries/put-selector/0.3.5',
        'dgrid': 'http://devstatic/libraries/dgrid/0.3.16',
        'xstyle': 'http://devstatic/libraries/xstyle/0.1.3',
        'toastr': 'http://devstatic/libraries/toastr/1.2.2-514cc12',
        ...
    },
    packages:
    [
    {
        name: "jquery",
        location: "http://devstatic/libraries/jquery/1.8.3",
        main: "jquery"
    },
    {
        name: "jquerybase64",
        location: "http://devstatic/libraries/jquery/1.8.3",
        main: "jquery.base64"
    },
    {
        name: "dojo",
        location: "http://devstatic/libraries/dojo-debug/1.10.4/dojo"
    },
    {
        name: "dijit",
        location: "http://devstatic/libraries/dojo-debug/1.10.4/dijit"
    },
    {
        name: "dojox",
        location: "http://devstatic/libraries/dojo-debug/1.10.4/dojox"
    },
    {
        name: "intern",
        location: "/base/Tools/Intern/node_modules/intern"
    },
    {
        name: "karma",
        location: "/base/Tools/Karma"
    }
    ],
    deps: null,
    callback: null
};
```

And here I am in a major problem. How do I communicate the 3rd party versions loaded from **ThirdPartyJsLibRootMap.json** over to `Tools/Karma/dojo-config.js`?

I mean, those versions are known at the time `karma.conf.js` is processed and if I could inject them into the html page generated by karma then I could reference them from `Tools/Karma/dojo-config.js` and compose the right third party URLs. Alas, so far found no way to do it.

So, basically I have the following questions:

1. What is the right way to refer to http URLs in karma.conf.js? The answer could be - don't, but then how do I make it loaded by the generated html page?
2. If loading http URLs the way I do it in karma.conf.js is fine, then how to specify expressions like `**`?
3. How to make the information computed in karma.conf.js available to the javascript loaded in the browser? This information is known at the "node time" (when karma.conf.js is run), but I am puzzled as to how to make it available at the "browser time".